# pylab imshow color not fully showing

Tags: opencv, matplotlib, rgb, imshow

I have been trying to implement some image processing techniques with an opened image via pylab. The problems is, I can open and see the image thru pylab, but the color seems to be very different. It doesn't seem that the red colors are displayed.

> The image shown with Pylab

[image]

> The original image (and when it is shown with cv2.imshow

[image]

Anyone can help me make pylab work appropriately? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color appears different because of the different color order used in OpenCV and Matplotlib:

- OpenCV uses BGR format by default.
- Matplotlib uses RGB format by default.

As you can see the channels are reversed, hence you get a weird colored object.

**Case 1:** If you are reading the image using `cv2.imread()`

- You can display with `cv2.imshow()` without any problem.
- But if you are displaying it using `imshow()` of Matplotlib, then you have to reverse the channels. `plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))`

**Case 2:** If you are reading the image using `cv2.imread()`

- You can display with `plt.imshow()` of Matplotlib without any problem.
- But if you are displaying it using `cv2.imshow()` of OpenCV, then again you have to reverse the channels. `cv2.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))`

**Case 3:** If you are unsure about how your image was read simply swap the first and last channels:
`cv2.imshow('Image', im[...,::-1])`

Comment: I fixed it by following the solution for Case 1. Thank you very much!